# An odd subset of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: general-topology

The problem is for my topology course, and it is to find a subset of $\mathbb Q$ which is neither open nor closed relative to the real line, but is clopen relative to $\mathbb Q$. I noticed immediately that the problem can be solved trivially by choosing $\mathbb Q$ as the subset in question, and noting that any set is both open and closed relative to itself. I get the feeling though that this is not what the professor had in mind when assigning the question, but I'm struggling to find any other set.

For clarity's sake, I'd like to point out that the professor's definition of open and closed are a bit different than what's usually used. In this context, an open set $S$ is defined as a set such that for any $s \in S,$ there is a neighborhood of $s$ denoted $N_s = D^n (s,r)$ where $n$ is the dimension of the Euclidean space in question, in this case 1, and $r$ is the radius, such that $N_s\subset S$. I guess a more compact way of saying this would be that there exists an $r$ with this property.

Closed is defined similarly - that for any $x \notin S$, there exists an $r$ such that $N_x \cap S = \emptyset$.

Relative sets are then defined in the usual way, as I understand, with the old neighborhoods being intersected with the set in question.

Comment: I think the solution you found is actually the best one. This is what I would hand in if I were you. If you still wish to find other solutions, you can take any ray with irrational endpoint.

Comment: Yes. Or any finite union of intervals with irrational endpoints. Why not give more than one example? Yours and Amitai's.

Comment: Why not ask your professor for clarity?

Comment: @ user10676 I would give your comment +5 if I could.

Comment: Well, you see, it was 2 AM when I decided that my insomnia was going to prohibit sleep tonight, and it was either do measure theory homework, or topology. Now it's nearly 5 AM, and my lecture isn't for another 5 hours. The idea was to be productive while not sleeping.

But yeah. I'll ask her then.

Comment: Also as much as I appreciate the helpful comments, I can't upvote stuff because I goofed my mergesave and mergedelete in the profile, so I have no reputation anymore. So please, accept my +1's in spirit.

Comment: Your own solution is ideal. If you wanted more such clopen subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, you could take any set $\mathbb{Q}\cap D^1(s,r)$ such that $s+r$ and $s-r$ are not rational.

Comment: With just an open interval like that, it would be open relative to the real line. The subset has to be neither open nor closed relative to $\mathbb R$ and clopen in $\mathbb Q$. Perhaps a half-open interval?

Comment: That open interval is not open in the reals, as it contains only rationals, and every open interval in the reals contains irrationals as well.